# Angular - Focus event being called on lost focus

Tags: javascript, angular

I've come across some kind of bug I believe with angular and chrome and I am not quite sure what the solution is, my angular application has custom input controls and these inputs do some stuff on focus `(focus)="someEvent($event)`. These inputs are the username and password field so chrome stores the values. Upon loading the page again, chrome will apply the stored values, if a user clicks elsewhere on the screen (NOT on the input components), both of the input components fire the focus event.

I could understand if this happened on page load as chrome may cycle through the inputs and apply the stored values, however this happens after the first mouse click anywhere on the page.

Is there a way to interpret that these focus events were cause by the autofill feature and not the user focusing on the input manually?

I have some code on these events that do `event.target.select()` to select all text, and oddly enough.. the 2 inputs end up getting stuck in a focus loop. The first gets focused then the second then the first then the second forever until a user presses tab.

HTML:

```
<input [ngClass]="inputClass" [type]="this.type" [readOnly]="this.readonly || (this.ParentPanel && this.ParentPanel.readonly)" [ngStyle]="inputStyle" [disabled]="disabled || (this.ParentPanel && this.ParentPanel.disabled)" [(ngModel)]="value" (change)="Event_change($event)" (keyup)="Event_keyup($event)" (keydown)="Event_keydown($event)" (focus)="Event_focus($event)" maxlength="512"/>
```

TS:

```
Event_focus(event) {
    console.log('focus event' , event);
    if (this.selectAllOnFocus) {
      setTimeout(() => { // required to work with Edge (OnFocus happens before some browser properties are set)
        event.target.select();
      });
    }
    this.OnFocus.emit(event);
  }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out, Before the code gets called - I have it check whether or not the control is the documents activeElement.

```
if (this.selectAllOnFocus && this.element && this.element.nativeElement === document.activeElement) { //do rest here }
```

These appears to work and resolve my issue.